# Why I can't find the eigenvectors of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, determinant

Let  $V=\mathbb{C^2}$, vector space over the field $\mathbb{C}$,
and let  $T:V \rightarrow V$ be defined by $T(z,w)=(z+iw, iz+w)$. I am asked to prove that T is diagonalizable (i.e., that there is a basis $\beta \subset V $
such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix).
I proposed the set $\delta=\{(1,0),(0,i)\}$ and calculated the solutions for the characteristic polynomial of $[T]_\delta$, in order to figure out a set of eigenvalues for T, and thus, a couple of linearly independent eigenvectors.

Since  $[T]_\delta$ $= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$, then the characteristic polynomial of $[T]_\delta$ is $f(t)=det( [T]_\delta -tI)=-(1-t)^2$, and thus $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Therefore the left multiplication by $( [T]_\delta -1I)$ is a non-invertible linear  transformation, which implies that there is some $v \in V$, with $v \neq 0$, such that $( [T]_\delta -1I)v=0$. However, when I try to find such a vector $v$, I am lead to the conclusion that $v=0$ (i. e. 
$( [T]_\delta -1I)v=0$ implies that $v=0$). But that contradicts the fact that $f(1)=0$. 
What is going on?

Comment: There is really no need to change basis first. You may just as well find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&i\\i&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You computed the characteristic polynomial incorrectly.  We have $$[T]_\delta -tI=\begin{pmatrix} 1-t & -1 \\ 1 & 1-t\end{pmatrix}$$ which has determinant $$(1-t)^2+1=t^2-2t+2,$$ not $-(1-t)^2$.